# How to create a transport in wso2 - esb developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When using wso2 developer studio to create a scenario in wso2 - esb, how do we create a transport from the UI ? I found that we can define the transport in the proxy service in text, but how to configure the properties of a transport within the UI ? Or is the inboundEndpoits the only method we can define a message in-point within the dev-studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add transport from the property view.

1. Right click on the proxy -> show propertties view
2. There is a property called transports under Basic. You can select transports from there

Hope this answers the question!